# Roslyn: Analyzing the object invoking the method

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

For instance:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader datareader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

The invocation node here is `command.ExecuteReader()`. How can I, using roslyn, get the variable identifier token/node of `command` from the invocation node? 
Assuming that this invocation node can have many other method calls before it, e.g. `classA.methodA().methodB().classB.methodC(command.ExecuteReader())` and hence getting identifiers through `node.DescendantNodes` might not be useful. 
The solution I thought of was to get the SpanStart of `ExecuteReader` first, then follow by getting the symbol of `command` by calling `SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPosition` with the position of `ExecuteReader.SpanStart - 2`. However I am unsure if this solution can handle every single situation. The application I am working on is a static code analyzer.

Comment: In the end those are just chained invocations/simple member accesses. If you get the inner-most invocation (or `SimpleMemberAccessExpression`) you have what you want. Look at the immediate parent instead of all ancestors.

Comment: is there like a better way instead of hard coding it? for example, getting the symbol of the method call, then from the symbol, determine the instance of an object invoking the method. for instance: `ClassA varA = new ClassA(); varA.methodA()` getting symbol of `methodA()` and finding out that `varA` invoked it.

Comment: What do you mean with "hard coding it"? If you want that invocation, you have to write code that gets the invocation.

Comment: Does my answer address your question? Is there any clarification or extension that I can make for you to accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have an invocation node, you can see whether its expression is a member access or not. If the invocation is for a statement "DoThis()" then there isn't a member access but if the invocation is for "x.DoThis()" then there *is* a member access since "DoThis" is being called against the reference "x".

Once you confirm that there *is* a member access, you may then get the expression of the target reference - this is the reference whose member is being accessed. This expression may be a simple name identifier (eg. "command") or it may be another member access (eg. "x.command") or it might be another invocation (eg. "GetCommand()") or it might be a combination of these.

To illustrate with code -

```
private static void AnalyseInvocation(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var invocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;
    var memberAccess = invocation.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
    if ((memberAccess == null) || (memberAccess.Name.Identifier.ValueText != "ExecuteReader"))
        return;

    if (memberAccess.Expression is IdentifierNameSyntax)
    {
        // The target is a simple identifier, the code being analysed is of the form
        // "command.ExecuteReader()" and memberAccess.Expression is the "command"
        // node
    }
    else if (memberAccess.Expression is InvocationExpressionSyntax)
    {
        // The target is another invocation, the code being analysed is of the form
        // "GetCommand().ExecuteReader()" and memberAccess.Expression is the
        // "GetCommand()" node
    }
    else if (memberAccess.Expression is MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)
    {
        // The target is a member access, the code being analysed is of the form
        // "x.Command.ExecuteReader()" and memberAccess.Expression is the "x.Command"
        // node
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm..but if its a long chain of invocation expression will it still work? for instance, `node.ChildNodes().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>().Single().Name`, from the syntax visualizer in visual studio, the invocation.express of Single() is `node.ChildNodes().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>().Single` which, from the syntax visualizer, is a `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax` hence it doesnt satisfy the condition of `"x.Command.ExecuteReader()"`, correct me if im wrong. thanks! and sorry for the very late reply. lol.

Comment: sorry i think i misunderstood your code, so you are actually checking `invocation.Expression.Expression` right? then in that case i think you are right on the approach

Comment: @KimKangIn yes, I am essentially checking invocation.Expression.Expression - this will return the full chain before the "ExecuteReader" call, no matter how simple or complex that chain is. I've changed the code example slightly to ignore any invocation that isn't for "ExecuteReader" so that if you get this code running in the IDE  and put a breakpoint on the first "if (memberAccess.Expression is .." line then you'll see by inspecting the memberAccess reference that it is always *everything* before "ExecuteReader" in the invocation.